# donde está el error de sintaxis en el if del código python

Tags: python, string, booleano, sintaxis

Estoy intentando crear un mini CAS para mis estudiantes, y para evitar que el `-` de opuesto de, el programa lo tome como un `-` de restar puse lo siguiente:

```
operador=["+","-","*","/","^"]
    for i in operador:
         if (i in entrada) and not(i="-" and entrada.find("-")==0 or (entrada[entrada.find("-")-1] in ["+", "-", "*", "/", "(","|","^"])):
             recursivo=True
```

pero me da un error en el if de sintaxis y no lo puedo encontrar.

Comment: `not(i="-"` debería ser `not(i=="-"`, supongo

Comment: y no se si es valido en python como está, pero yo rodearia con parentesis todo entre el `"if"` y el `":"`

Answer (score 1):

Parece que en lugar de la condición `i=="-"` has escrito `i="-"`.

No obstante voy a aprovechar la respuesta para refactorizar un poco el código y hacerlo más legible (y por tanto más mantenible). Ya que Python admite retornos de carro dentro de una expresión entre paréntesis, podemos encerrar toda la condición tras el `if` entre paréntesis para así poder partirla en varias líneas y leerla mejor.

Primera refactorización, sólo reformatear:

```
operador=["+","-","","/","^"]
for i in operador:
    if ((i in entrada) 
        and not (i=="-" and entrada.find("-")==0
                 or (entrada[entrada.find("-")-1] in ["+","-","","/","(","|","^"])
                )
        ):
        recursivo=True
```

Entrando a ver qué se intenta evaluar en el `if`, veo `entrada.find("-")==0` que aparentemente trata de decidir si el primer carácter de `entrada` es un `"-"`. Podemos usar en su lugar `entrada.startswith("-")`, que parece más claro en cuanto a su intención.

¿Qué está evaluendo el `and not ( ... and ... or ...)`? Aparentemente, que no suceda una de las siguientes:

- Que `i` sea `"-"` (si lo es, ya no se cumple el `if`)
- Que `entrada` no comience por `"-"` (si comienza, ya no se cumple el `if`)
- Que, si se cumplen las dos anteriores, el carácter anterior al primer `"-"` sea uno de estos: `["+","-","","/","(","|","^"]`. Si no lo es, ya no se cumple el `if`.

Por tanto ese conjunto de caracteres podría denominarse "operadores válidos antes del menos".

Pero aún así, la lógica interna del `if` me resulta difícil de leer. Propongo deshacer ese único `if` en varios, testeando en cada uno la condición que me haría el `if` falso y saltando a la siguiente iteración (`continue`) cuando así ocurra.

Segunda refactorización. Cambiar condición compleja por varios `if`:

```
operador=["+","-","","/","^"]
operadores_validos_ante_menos = ["+","-","","/","(","|","^"]
for i in operador:
    if i not in entrada:  # Saltarse operadores que no estén en la entrada
        continue
    if i != "-":          # Saltarse operadores que no sean el "-"
        continue
    if entrada.startswith("-"):  # Saltarse el - si está al inicio
        continue
    if entrada[entrada.find("-")-1] in operadores_validos_ante_menos:
        continue
    recursivo=True
```

Creo que, si no me he equivocado, esta implementación captura la misma condición que implementaste en tu compleja expresión booleana (he hecho algunos tests y devuelve los mismos resultados). No tengo claro no obstante si hace lo que esperabas. Quizás el reescribirlo de esta otra forma te haga más fácil ver algún posible fallo en su lógica.

Comment: gracias por tomarse el tiempo. Algunas de tus ideas son interesantes y bienvenidas. en todo caso el if programa funciona como lo esperaba en este momento

Comment: una aclaracion la linea con la que me conformé fue:  if ("-" in entrada) and not(entrada.find("-")==0 or (entrada[entrada.find("-")-1] in ["+","-","*","/","(","|","^"])):

Answer (score -1):

Primer error, tienes identado el for despues de operador
Segundo error: not(i="-"...) cambiar por not(i=="-"...

Aquí el código corregido

```
operador = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
for i in operador:
    if i in entrada and not (i == '-' and entrada.find('-') == 0
                             or entrada[entrada.find('-') - 1] in [
        '+',
        '-',
        '*',
        '/',
        '(',
        '|',
        '^',
        ]):
        recursivo = True
```

Comment: Hola LPZ. El indentado del `for` lo hizo un editor (el autor originalmente no lo habia formateado el codigo). Respecto al otro error, es un error tipografico. Como sí usó bien el comparador, pienso que cuando usó la asignacion se equivocó al escribir. Estas preguntas han de comentar el error y no responder, si no reportar para su cierre como No relacionado > Error tipografico. Recuerda leer [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. Un saludo

Comment: la pregunta era sobre error de sintaxis, básicamente, "donde me equivoque en escribir", obviamente la respuesta iba a ser "te equivocaste en escribir en esta parte". Pregunta - Respuesta.

Comment: Seria error de sintaxis y bueno para responder si siempre usase el `= ` para comprarar. Se le explicaria la sintaxis. En este caso sabe que `==` es para comparar porque lo usa  y por ello pienso que se equivocó al escribir, ergo error tipografico.